# Extract any audio from container with ffmpeg

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

Is there a way to use `-acodec copy` with `-vn` to:

- Extract the audio stream from a container, such as mp4
- **Without** knowing the audio codec beforehand
- And save it to an audio file with the appropriate extension

Comment: What is the "appropriate extension"? You could use Matroska (.mka) or maybe NUT (.nut) with most audio formats, but I doubt that is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this isn't a simple option in ffmpeg is because you need a way to decide what container to use for the output.

If you determined which file extension to use for each codec, and named the file with that extension, ffmpeg would write the output file in the right container for you. The (unfortunately) simplest way to do this that I can think of is a Python 2 script:

```py
import re
import subprocess
import sys

EXTENSIONS_BY_CODEC = {'mp3': '.mp3', 'aac': '.m4a'}
# Add more codecs as desired

_, infile, outfile = sys.argv
_, detect_data = subprocess.Popen(('ffmpeg', '-i', infile),
                                  stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
codec = re.search(r'Audio: ([^,]+),', detect_data).group(1)
if codec in EXTENSIONS_BY_CODEC:
    sys.exit(subprocess.call(('ffmpeg', '-i', infile, '-acodec', 'copy', '-vn',
                              outfile + EXTENSIONS_BY_CODEC[codec])))
else:
    print >>sys.stderr, 'Extension not found for codec:', codec
    sys.exit(2)
```

Comment: The `EXTENSIONS_BY_CODEC` is non-exhaustive to FFmpeg's support of codecs, and it is kinda bulky to carry a Python executable sometimes.

Answer (score -4):

take a look at handbrake, gui for ffmpeg with commandline (and command)  output (if you want to port it to a script of some sort)

Comment: How does this help? It just does the same things as ffmpeg with a gui, which is not what OP is asking for.